# returning list data on POST in django-tastypie

Tags: django, post, tastypie

I know `always_return_data = True` makes tastypie return object after creation.

I'd like to return a list of data upon object creation.
(when a user `like` a post, I return all likes-info for the post)

Is this a bad practice?
I could do this easily in a regular django view, but having hard time with tastypie.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only thing I can think of would be to create a `Mixin` for `Resource`/`ModelResource` with a different `post_list`/`put_detail`/`put_list` that takes care of this.  Check out [resources.py](https://github.com/toastdriven/django-tastypie/blob/v0.9.11/tastypie/resources.py) for the functions that you'd need to change.